# Check server's free and reserved CPU

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to check the free and reserved CPU in a linux server.
I found this command `mpstat` and below is the output:

```
CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
all    7.13    0.00    2.46    1.73    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.00   88.59
```

If %idle is e.g 1.0% it means that I am using 99.00% of the available CPU?
Is there a better way to find this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, install the `htop` tool. I love it and have used so many times. It is like `top` but better and prettier with more options. To get the `CPU average` do following steps:

- execute `htop`
- press `f2` to enter setup
- press `3 x right arrow key`
- press `36 x down arrow key` to `CPU average`
- press `2 x Enter` or optionally move it where you want it to be with the arrow keys
- optionally press the `Spacebar` as many times as you want to change the display format

I would recommend you to explore the `htop` command, it has so many options :)

---

You can get the `mpstat output explanation` by running this:

```bash
man mpstat
```

You will get this output:

```
CPU     Processor number. The keyword all indicates that statistics are calculated as averages among all processors.
%usr    Show the percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the user level (application).
%nice   Show the percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the user level with nice priority.
%sys    Show the percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the system level (kernel). Note that this does not include time spent servicing hard‐ ware and software interrupts.
%iowait Show the percentage of time that the CPU or CPUs were idle during which the system had an outstanding disk I/O request.
%irq    Show the percentage of time spent by the CPU or CPUs to service hardware interrupts.
%soft   Show the percentage of time spent by the CPU or CPUs to service software interrupts.
%steal  Show the percentage of time spent in involuntary wait by the virtual CPU or CPUs while the hypervisor was servicing another virtual processor.
%guest  Show the percentage of time spent by the CPU or CPUs to run a virtual processor.
%gnice  Show the percentage of time spent by the CPU or CPUs to run a niced guest.
%idle   Show the percentage of time that the CPU or CPUs were idle and the system did not have an outstanding disk I/O request.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across the term "reserved CPU" in relation to Linux. Certainly with some hypervisors the meaning of the % utlization figures can have different interpretations than with a baremetal machine. I'll assume by "reserved" you mean it's doing something.

> If %idle is e.g 1.0% it means that I am using 99.00% of the available CPU?

Short answer: yes

Longer answer: Not necessarily. Some of the time reported as iowait can be used by the CPU for other things.

> Is there a better way to find this info?

Define "better"